# Action on the arrayController from the CollectionView template

Tags: ember.js

- I have a personArrayController with an addField and deleteField methods
- I have a PersonCollectionView class (inherited from CollectionView)
- HandleBars is making the connection:
  {{view PersonCollectionView contentBinding="personArrayController"}}
- I need to have a button in each view of the collectionView to allow deleting the selected element.

The child View template needs to call the deleteField from the personArrayController. target is used because otherwise the router will be triggered.

Display of the views is done correctly but when I click on a "delete" button the target is not found (the personArrayController is not triggered).

How can I access the personArrayController from my template view ?
I was thinking this controller was accessible with the target="view.content"...but it seems logical the "view.content" is the current array element and not the arrayController...

```
App.PersonCollectionView=Ember.CollectionView.extends({
itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(<button {{action deleteField view.content target="view.content"}});
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify "controller" as target:

```
App.PersonCollectionView=Ember.CollectionView.extends({
itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(<button {{action deleteField view.content target="controller"}});
  })
})
```

Comment: Tx for your answer. it works but to make it works I need to change my Handlebars call to {{view PersonCollectionView contentBinding="personArrayController" controllerBinding="personArrayController"}}. Is there a better solution to avoid filling the contentBinding AND the controllerBinding attributes ?

Comment: I am always using the each helper : {{#each item in controller}}. So i can't help you on this task.